# comparing two arrays in c++ and returning values depending on matches or non matches of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I need to write a function that will compare two arrays, its for comparing a lottery ticket's numbers to the winning numbers, and it needs to return 1 for every  number that matches and a 0 for every number that doesnt match. I use two arrays to  store the numbers but i am having difficulties printing out the nonmatched ones correctly, this is the little program i wrote i cant figure out how to put the part that prints the 0 for a non matched element

```
    int main() {
    int i,j;
    int flag=0;
    int a[]={3,49,25,48,12,33};
    int b[]={3,48,15,33,12,44};
    for( i=0;i<6;i++){
        for( j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(a[i]==b[j]){
                cout<<"1 "<<endl;
                break;
            }

            else flag=1;


        }

    }
if(flag==1){
    cout<<0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing each element of `a` to every element in `b`, which I'm sure isn't your intention. You should trace your program's logic with pencil and paper to see what is happening. It will compare `a[0]` to every element in `b`, then it compares `a[1]` to every element in `b`, and so on. The only possible way all of these comparisons will be equal is if all the numbers in both arrays are equal.

Comment: @FeiXiang Might be usefull if one or both arrays aren't sorted or otherwise ordered.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - that can be addressed by sorting the arrays before comparing (or creating copies, sorting the copies, and comparing them).     However, Fei Xiang raises a good point - the question is not clear on what is considered to be a match or non-match.    In the example given, is there only one match (the pair of threes as the first element) or four (if the arrays were both sorted there would be four elements equal and one non-equal)?

Comment: @Peter Even if sorted, the numbers might not be in the corresponding indexes in both arrays (especially considering the "ticket" or "lottery use-case). So a single straight comparison loop is not enough.

Comment: @FeiXiang No actually that was my intention, sorry for not making it clearer. It is like the a[] is the lottery ticket numbers and b[] are the drawn numbers, and then i wanna take the first ticket number and see if it exists anywhere is the array of drawn numbers then do the same with the second icket number and so on. But my problem is that i want to return only one number for every match or non match, and not return a number everytime an element doesnt match, for example with 49 i want to check it with every number in the second array and then print only one 0 and not 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide in the inner loop, if 0 or 1 has to be printed, but print out in outer loop:

```
for(i)
{
    char c = '0';
    for(j)
    {
        if(==)
        {
            c = '1';
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << c << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide which of the number arrays is the "draw" and which is the "ticket". Better and more descriptive naming helps there.

Then you add a third `bool` array, corresponding to the "ticket" array, and initialize all elements to `false`. When you iterate over the number arrays, and the comparison is `true` then you set the corresponding element of the `bool` array to `true`.

After the comparison, the `bool` array will contain `true` elements for each number of the "ticket" that matched a number of the "draw".

Disclaimer: This is only *one* of many possible solutions. It's maybe not the best, and maybe not exactly what you want.

Comment: Variant might be placing an index *where* the match occurred instead of just `true`. Maybe this information is useful later?

Answer (score 0):

This wont be the more *efficient* way to do it, but I hope that the following is an easy to understand solution, and that it serve you as a introduction to some useful tools in C++, which are for example the `std::vector` containers, which you should learn:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::size_t> a={3,49,25,48,12,33};
    std::vector<std::size_t> b={3,48,15,33,12,44};
    std::size_t size (a.size());
    std::vector<std::size_t> count_correct;
    for( std::size_t i=0;i<size;i++) {

        for( std::size_t j=0;j<size;j++){
            if(a[i]==b[j]){
                count_correct.push_back(1);
                break;
            } 
        }
    }

    for (std::size_t i(0); i<count_correct.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
    std::size_t incorrect_times (size - count_correct.size());
    for (std::size_t i(0); i<incorrect_times; ++i) {
        std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
   }

return 0;
}
```